# Implementing a CRTP linked list mix-in C++

Tags: c++, templates, mixins, crtp

I'm having trouble getting a CRTP mixin to work.

Here is the stripped down implementation:

```
template < typename T >
class AutoSList : public T {
public:
  AutoSList() {}

  ~AutoSList() : _next(nullptr) {}


private:
  static T* _head;
  static T* _tail;
  T* _next;

};

// I really hate this syntax.
template <typename T>
T*  AutoSList<T>::_head = nullptr;
template <typename T>
T*  AutoSList<T>::_tail = nullptr;

class itsybase : public AutoSList < itsybase >
{

};
```

I'm using VS2013 and getting the following errors:

```
   error C2504: 'itsybase' : base class undefined
 : see reference to class template instantiation 'AutoSList<itsybase>' being compiled
```

I have no idea what's going wrong, any suggestions?

Comment: It's a typo. Your class name is Auto**S**List but you declare a constructor by the name of AutoList. Same with destructor.

Comment: @AllanDeutsch: please do not change the code or other parts of the question after answers have been posted. that can easily invalidate the answers. instead, if you must, *add* to the question, but if that information makes it very different, then ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's 2 problems causing those compilation errors. First is a typo causing mismatch with c-tor/d-tor and class name.

The second problem is that you're trying to inherit `T` in the parent template. That's not possible in CRTP because the type will not be complete by the time the template is instantiated. That would cause an infinitely recursive inheritance anyway: `itsybase` inherits `AutoSList<itsybase>` which inherits `itsybase` which inherits `AutoSList<itsybase>`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4173298/1514515 I looked at this and other similar posts, it appears to be doing the same thing.
EDIT: Nevermind I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo, as `user2079303` suggested.  Here's what `clang++` says about it:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -c go.cpp 
go.cpp:6:5: error: missing return type for function 'AutoList'; did you mean the constructor name 'AutoSList'?
    AutoList() {}
    ^~~~~~~~
    AutoSList
go.cpp:8:6: error: expected the class name after '~' to name a destructor
    ~AutoList() {}
     ^~~~~~~~
     AutoSList
go.cpp:20:19: error: no member named '_head' in 'AutoSList<T>'
T*  AutoSList<T>::_head = nullptr;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
go.cpp:24:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ADLib'
class itsybase : public ADLib::AutoSList < itsybase >
                        ^
4 errors generated.
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it to reflect those changes, still got a couple errors.

Comment: @AllanDeutsch please explicitly outline updates in your question, otherwise you're invalidating the answers. If the update prompts a completely new problem, please open a new question.